# Arquillian - How to start a container programmatically

Tags: testing, containers, jboss-arquillian

How do we start the container dynamically using Arquillian, I have a use case to test where I have to start the container dynamically during the execution of the test.

I have went through Cargo framework and it seems that they have given the control to the developer to start the container dynamically - http://cargo.codehaus.org/Quick+start, in this they start the container explicitly using start() method, by this we can start as many containers as possible with the specified configuration. Similarly to Cargo is there an API(s) from Arquillian where we can achieve this similar behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to perform starting the container at runtime, please see below GitHub URL:

https://github.com/saikiran939/arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arquillian/tomcat/managed/TestArquillianTomcatManaged.java